# How to make the Reyes' Instagram Filter?

Tags: post-processing, effect, instagram

I would like to know how we can make the same thing that the Reyes Instagram filter gives on a picture on Photoshop?

Before (left) / After (right):
[image: Reyes Instagram Filter Example]

Comment: Can you please include a link to a specific example of such a filter, including an identical photo without the filter.

Answer (score 5):

I think it can be archieved by lowering the black and white values in the curves and finally giving the diagram a slight curve towards top to strengthen white and lowering blacks further.

The curves look this (in Gimp, can be archieved in any other tool too):

[image: Values used (Gimp)]

I've cropped the original side of your image and used with the above values. Here's waht it looks like:

[image: Filter reverse engineered by using curves]